# Is there a way to create a subplot that contains plots created inside functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a subplot with 4 figures. However, my plots are created within functions.... e.g.:

```
def random(x):
    variable_x = x
    result = f(x)
    plt.plot(result, x)
    plt.show()

random(x)
```

I have four of these functions for different purposes but would like to use all four plots on the same subplot. is this possible? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will make life much easier for yourself if you make the function "single responsibility" and let it return the result and do the plotting from the outside:

```
def random(x):
    variable_x = x
    return result = f(x)

result = random(x)
plt.plot(result, x)
plt.show()
```

You will also be able to test these more easily. 

If you are determined to do the plotting inside, you could pass in a plot function:

```
def random(x, show):
    variable_x = x
    result = f(x)
    show(result)

def show(result):
    plt.plot(result, x)
    plt.show()

result = random(x, show)
```

This would allow you to control which function shows where.